# Real functions vanishing at infinity

Tags: general-topology

I am reading Simmons' Topology book. A function $f$ defined on a locally compact Hausdorf space $X$ is said to vanish at infinity if for each $\epsilon>0$ there exists a compact subspace $C$ of $X$ such that $|f(x)|<\epsilon$ for every $x$ outside of $C$. It also says that if $X$ is compact, every real function defined on $X$ vanishes at infinity. I don't understand why. Could you help me see the reason, please?

Comment: By definition.  Did you read the definition of 'vanishing at $\infty$' ?

Comment: The statement makes no sense to me. Perhaps you could give a more detailed quote from the book.

Comment: I have updated the question by giving the definition of '' vanishing at infinity''.

Comment: Can you find such a compact subspace? (Hint: a space is always a subspace of itself)

Comment: @Trebor, but ouside of that subspace will be empty, wright?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth